# Xamarin Forms | Center the splash screen | iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, splash-screen

Whenever I load up my app with a custom splash screen, the screen is always not centered; it is always half off the screen to the right. When I adjust it for the iPhone 5s, all of the other phone types have the screen off center.

Is there a certain way to center the image on the splash screen 100 % of the time?

Comment: Are you using different splash screens for different screen dimensions?

Comment: I want a splash screen that automatically adjusts to any screen dimension

Comment: You have to include multiple splash screens which are all of the different required dimensions. You can't just use 1 file for all screen sizes, otherwise it will cause lots of scaling differences throughout your application.